# Changing the Type of an unknown reflected class to a generic type

Tags: java, generics, reflection, dependency-injection, type-conversion

### Introduction

I'm Implementing Dependency Injection into my code.

I've gotten to a point where I have a properties file configured named config.properties. I also know how to reflect the property strings into an object.

### The Problem

The problem is that when I do this reflection java says the type is going to be `Class<?>` and I want it to be a generic type `D` so I can reuse the code that's coupled with this class.

### Where I'm At

Below is the code where `D` is my generic object I want to cast to. `ObjectImplementation` is the layer of abstraction (so every object that gets used on this class implements that interface). `SalesRepbyID` is just the name of the container class. `fileparser` is a different part of the dependency injection (ignore that for now). And finally, Parse is the method that constructs the instances I need to cast.

I've googled the title and searched through Stackoverflow results as well as external webpages. I think what I'm missing is called a Factory Pattern but I'm unsure of how to implement such a thing or if I'm even on the right track.

### The Goal

The Goal here is to use the reflection and generic typing so that any Class that implements `ObjectImplementation` can be constructed in this container class and the implementation to use can be changed through the properties file and NOT the code. Any silly things I'm doing with regard to naming conventions please let me know and thanks as always for your efforts.

```
public class SalesRepbyId<D extends ObjectImplementation> implements 
DataParserImplementation<Map<String,D>> {
private FileParserImplementation<ArrayList<String[]>> FileParser;

public SalesRepbyId(FileParserImplementation<ArrayList<String[]>> FileParser){
    this.FileParser = FileParser;

}
@Override
public Map<String, D> Parse() {
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    try {
        prop.load(Data_Parser.class.getResourceAsStream("config.properties"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e + " error with config.properties I/O");
    }
    try {
        Class<?> classToUse = Class.forName(prop.getProperty("ObjectImplementation"));

//construct classToUse instances here in the method many times with type D
```

Comment: Concrete generic type arguments are erased at runtime. So as the class is not known at compile time, you cannot get the `D` type. You don't have type safety, and can't get it.

Comment: So I'm thinking the wrong way? And by wrong way I mean like wrong method to acheive my goal

Comment: Not exactly. You just should not expect type safety. You can still use `classToUse.newInstance().parseMethod()` (or whatever your method name is). But `D` is and will remain unknown. As the "config" is in the application, chances are you can redesign your code to make the configuration supply some kind of enum, based on which you can pick an implementation from something checked at compile-time...

Comment: You can get a `Class<? extends ObjectImplementation>` by saying `Class.forName(...).asSubclass(ObjectImplementation.class)`. That will let you create instances of `ObjectImplementation`. Otherwise, it doesn't look to me like you should be using generics here, because it seems like you're saying that the actual type of `D` is being specified by the file.

Comment: If I take your solution then any class that implements ObjectImpl. and is in the config file will work right? I thought I needed D so that I could make generic instances such that any class with ObjectImpl as the parent could be used there. As long as I can do that my problem is solved.

Comment: You can still even make this `SalesRepbyId.parse()` method generic to make it easy on the callers. But it will still be unsafe. Have you considered the `enum` approach I alluded to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, in cases like this, what you can do is pass the `Class<D>` in when you construct the `SalesRepById`:

```
class SalesRepById<D extends ...> {
    private Class<D> typeOfD;

    SalesRepById(..., Class<D> typeOfD) {
        ...
        this.typeOfD = typeOfD;
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, D> parse() {
        try {
            Class<? extends D> typeFromFile =
                Class.forName(...).asSubclass(typeOfD);

            D instanceOfD =
                typeFromFile.getConstructor().newInstance();

        ...
    }
}
```

(See [`Class.asSubclass`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#asSubclass-java.lang.Class-), which is for down-casting a `Class` instance. For example, if I said `Class<?> c = String.class;`, I could say `c.asSubclass(CharSequence.class)` to get a `Class<? extends CharSequence>`. However, `Integer.asSubclass(CharSequence.class)` would throw an exception.)

This means that you have to know the actual type of `D` at compile-time and at the time of the object's construction:

```
SalesRepById<ActualType> srbid =
    new SalesRepById<>(..., ActualType.class);
```

What makes me nervous about that is that it seems like you're saying the actual type of `D` is specified by the file. In that case, I don't think you should have a type parameter for `D`. It seems like you should be using something like this instead:

```
class SalesRepById {
    SalesRepById(...) {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, ObjectImplementation> parse() {
        try {
            Class<? extends ObjectImplementation> typeFromFile =
                Class.forName(...).asSubclass(ObjectImplementation.class);

            ObjectImplementation instance =
                typeFromFile.getConstructor().newInstance();

        ...
    }
}
```

This still lets the file specify the exact subtype to use, and you don't have to know it at compile-time.

Just as a general rule, reflection and generics don't mix well. Reflection is run-time-only and generics are compile-time-only.

Comment: I solved my own problem thanks to the previous comments + some research and then came back and saw this just now. Since I basically did what this proposed I'm accepting it because it was very helpful.